# Intercept TCP and UDP traffic localhost

Tags: c#, tcp, udp, sniffing, interception

Is there a way to intercept TCP and UDP traffic that is inside localhost on Windows in C#? For example an app running on localhost sending messages through TCP and/or UDP on localhost... I need to intercept these to determine the efficiency of data of the program, for this I'm building an utility tool in C# (need a self build solution no product)

Comment: Maybe you could look at libpcap and the various customisations WireShark give you for your program, check out http://wiki.wireshark.org/Development

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually you have to use program like wireshark to capture loopback (127.0.0.1) traffic, but it's impossible for libpcap on Windows. (read [this note](http://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/Loopback))

You have to use [Raw Cap](http://www.netresec.com/?page=Blog&month=2011-04&post=RawCap-sniffer-for-Windows-released) if you want to sniff the loopback interface